# Word for 'cynical,' 'disdainful,' 'too cool for school'

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to summarize an attitude but can't think of the word.

Examples:
When a teen sneers and says, "High school? I'm so over it." Or says, "OK, boomer," and doesn't take advice, or a tradition or heritage seriously.

The closest I can think of are cynical, disdainful, 'over it,'dismissive.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have successfully started a list of synonyms that might also include *derisive*, *supercilious*, *sneering* and *contemptuous*. If you want a word that is from a slightly lower register to fit with a casual teen world, you might use *snooty*, a word which, according to Google ngram, was popular in the middle and last parts of the 20th Century.

A quick dictionary check will give you meanings similar to these from the Cambridge dictionary:

> *supercilious* = behaving as if you are better than other people, and that their opinions, beliefs, or ideas are not important
>
> *derisive* = showing the attitude in which someone or something is laughed at and considered stupid or of no value
>
> *sneering* = rude and not showing respect
>
> *snooty* = seeming by your manner to think that you are better than everyone else: